# How to subtract from one variable while adding to another

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an app in Swift that deals with time calculations.

I need to set it up so when I get a number in seconds that is greater then 60, it will +1 to the minutes variable and -60 from the seconds variable. It should only do this when the seconds are greater than 60.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your problem, what is stopping you from solving this yourself or at least trying to solve it yourself?

Comment: What Joakim said. But also make sure you’re actually solving the right problem.  Consider the desired and actual results if 35 secs is added twice.

Comment: I'm not too proficient in swift wanted to get some ideas from other people.

Comment: In the end this really hs nothing to do with Swift. If you know how to do this in, well, any other language, you can do it here. (Or are you having a hard time doing it in iOS? VERY different question - but it still gets to you providing more code you've tried, being more specific, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to convert seconds into minutes and seconds, using integer division and modulus.

```
// Starting value (seconds)
let input_seconds = 74

// Get minutes using integer division (this ignores the remainder - sometimes called floor division)
let minutes = input_seconds / 60

// Use modulus operator to get remainder, which is number of additional seconds
let seconds = input_seconds % 60

// Print output. You could use a number formatter to do formatting for you.
print("Output is \(minutes) minutes and \(seconds) seconds.")
```